# Material select error state is not triggered when trying to change step

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a vertical, linear material stepper (Angular Material2), in Angular 4, and when I attempt to change steps the error state for my two selects are not triggered. It works perfectly fine for inputs.

I have created a custom error state matcher, but that is only useful when clicking on a button to move next - not when trying to change step by clicking the step headers as it can't be intercepted. The error matcher check whether the control is valid, and whether the user has tried to navigate to another step. Bizarrely this does make the select activate its error classes, (turns to warn colour), but the mat error is not displayed. I thought this was because there was something wrong with the mat error, but if I make an error state matcher that just returns true, with no checking involved, it does display the mat error. Is there a reason for this and a way around it?

**component.html**

```
<mat-vertical-stepper linear #stepper>
<mat-step label="Organisation" formGroupName="organisation" [stepControl]="form.get('organisation')">
    <div class="field-container">
        <mat-form-field class="field">
            <input matInput placeholder="Organisation name" formControlName="name">
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('organisation.name').hasError('required')">
                You must enter an organisation name
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('organisation.name').hasError('minlength')">
                Organisation name must be at least 2 characters long
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="field">
            <input matInput placeholder="Organisation sector" formControlName="sector">
            <mat-error>
                You must enter an organisation sector
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="field">
            <mat-select placeholder="Number of employees" formControlName="employees" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of employeeQuantities" [value]="option.value">
                    {{ option.label }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>
                You must enter the number of employees within your organisation
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="field">
            <mat-select placeholder="Subdomain/URL" (change)="subdomainOptionSelected()" formControlName="subdomainOption" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of subdomainOptions" [value]="option.value">
                    {{ option.label }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>You must select a subdomain/URL</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="field" *ngIf="form.get('organisation.subdomainOption').value === 'Custom'">
            <input matInput placeholder="Custom Oporum subdomain" formControlName="subdomain">
            <span matPrefix>https://</span>
            <span matSuffix>.oporum.com</span>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('organisation.subdomain').hasError('required')">
                You must enter a subdomain
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('organisation.subdomain').hasError('minlength')">
                Subdomain name must be at least 2 characters long
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="stepper-nav-actions text-right">
            <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="next()" color="primary">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-step>
...
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatVerticalStepper;

private stepperButtons = {
    'Organisation': {
        submitted: false
    },
    'Administrator': {
        submitted: false
    },
    'Plan': {
        submitted: false
    },
    'Review': {
        submitted: false
    }
};

errorStateMatcher = {
    isErrorState: (control: FormControl | null) => {
        const submitted = this.stepperButtons[this.selectedStep.label].submitted;

        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || submitted));
    }
};

next() {
    this.stepperButtons[this.selectedStep.label].submitted = true;
    this.stepper.next();
}

get selectedStep() {
    return this.stepper.selected;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?